# Filtering aggregation issue on string type array values

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

We are indexing receivers of particular email,receiver may be single or may be multiple.

**Below are the properties**

1. `FieldName:Subject,Type:String,Analyzer:Keyword`
2. `FieldName:Receivers,Type:String,Analyzedr:Keyword`

**Date to Index**

1. `Subject:hello,Receivers:["A@abc.com","B@abc","C@abc.com"]`

The problem is while Filter aggregation is applied on terms aggregation. If "A@abc.com","B@abc" is filtered then logically it should only return "A@abc.com","B@abc" in term aggregation but it returns all "A@abc.com","B@abc",C@abc.com.

Below is my query and output.
**Input query**

```
{
"size":0,
"aggs":{
    "filter":{
        "filter":{
            "terms":{
                "receivers":[
                    "A@abc.com",
                    "B@abc"
                    ]
                }
        },
        "aggs":{
            "result":{
                "terms":{
                    "field":"receivers"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

**Output**

```
{
"took": 1,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": 26464,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
},
"aggregations": {
    "filter": {
        "doc_count": 1,
        "result": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "A@abc.com",
                    "doc_count": 1
                },
                {
                    "key": "B@abc",
                    "doc_count": 1
                },
                {
                    "key": "C@abc.net",
                    "doc_count": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}}
```

We even tried to use include but at some situation we may need to use regular expressions in include it self like below.Where we need "A@abc.com","B@abc" as well filter only  `".*abc.com.*"` from "A@abc.com","B@abc" only. so the output should be "A@abc.com" but it returns both "A@abc.com","B@abc"

```
{
"size":0,
"aggs":{
    "filter":{
        "filter":{
            "terms":{
                "receiver":[
                    "A@abc.com",
                    "B@abc.com"
                    ]
                }
        },
        "aggs":{
            "result":{
                "terms":{
                    "field":"receiver",
                    "include":[ ".*abc.com.*",
                        "A@abc.com",
                        "B@abc.com"
                        ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

Please suggest how can the above be achieved.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure the mapping is correct for your `receivers` field? Also, why not using `"index":"not_analyzed"` instead of `keyword` analyzer?

Comment: And it returns all the values because the you have an array of values there and the document matches, no matter how many values matched.

Comment: @AndreiStefan: Thank you for quick reply.You mean for array values there is not way to match only exact value?

Comment: Not the way you do it. Take a look at my answer using `include` for `terms`. That should work.

Comment: Is there any other way to handle string type array values to return only the filtered value from the array and not all the values?

Comment: Not quite, because the whole document matches, not individual values and those are returned. Also, ES gives you back the `_source` of the document which is the original json indexed. But, in your case, using `terms` aggregation the buckets returned can be filtered.

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be a bit different: when using a regular expression, this one shouldn't be in an array, but standalone. And the dot (`.`) should be escaped, as it's a reserved character:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "filter": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "receiver": [
            "A@abc.com",
            "B@abc.com"
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "result": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "receiver",
            "include": ".*abc\\.com.*"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```